# Forward Income Traffic from Client on Host to Container

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, docker

I use Ubuntu 16.04 right now.

I have an small office right now. In the past, the traffic like this:

> CLIENT --- SERVER --- ROUTER --- INTERNET

I set up the network like this:

1. I have an login page. If client hasn't entered the network, so client will be redirected to login page first.
2. If login success, I create iptables rules that let client access internet

So example like this:

- IP Client : 192.168.99.0/24
- IP Server : 192.168.0.15
- IP Page Login : 192.168.0.2 in port 4000 *(I use flask app)*

First what I do is, set up iptables rules that redirect all client to login page:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 192.168.99.0/24 -J REJECT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -s 192.168.99.0/24 -d 192.168.0.2 --dport 4000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -p tcp -s 192.168.99.0/24 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.2:4000
```

Than, if client open website (anything), client will be redirect to login page first. If login success, I create a new rule: *example: IP CLIENT: 192.168.99.100*

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -s 192.168.99.100 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s 192.168.99.100 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -o wlp3s0 -j MASQUERADE -s 192.168.99.100
```

That's work! Client can access internet. And now, I want to change the traffic, like this:

> CLIENT --- SERVER --- CONTAINER --- SERVER --- ROUTER --- INTERNET

I use docker container, inside the server. Or maybe if you want to see the image like this:

[image: Diagram]

So I want make 1 client have 1 container. So if there are 3 clients, there are 3 containers too. I made it because it makes easier to log the traffic from the client.

So my question is:

1. Can I just use iptables to this problem?
2. Can I route just one specific IP from client, to one specific IP container?

Or there is best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each container is listening on a different port on the local server doing the routing, it seems like you could use the source IP as the deciding factor in which port (container) it gets routed to.

For example, you have 3 containers each listening on separate ports 7771, 7772, 7772:

```
IF FROM CLIENT_1_SRC_IP -> localhost:7771
IF FROM CLIENT_2_SRC_IP -> localhost:7772
IF FROM CLIENT_3_SRC_IP -> localhost:7773
```

Keep in mind, **I have no idea what your "containers" are actually doing**, but **it's assumed they would be able to route the incoming traffic out to the internet appropriately once they accept the incoming packet.**

Also keep in mind that once the outbound traffic leaves the container, the Docker engine will automatically do the masquerading for that outbound traffic.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your answer. I know that container have port to publish to host. Like your example, first container publihs port on 7771. Than how can I route the incoming client 1 to port 7771?

Comment: Something like: `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s CLIENT_IP -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:7771`

Comment: I already try using DNAT. But after I think to use DNAT, DNAT is change the destination source from client right? Let's say client want to access 8.8.8.8. Than it will be change, and client access 127.0.0.1:7771. And client will never open 8.8.8.8. Is that right? Sorry I don't very understand about DNAT

Comment: I thought the goal was to route ALL traffic through the container (even traffic destined to 8.8.8.8) which is what DNAT will do, it will send everything to that destination. 

If you want to route specific packets to specific destinations you'll need to analyze the packet a bit more, for example something like `FORWARD -s CLIENT_IP -d 8.8.8.8 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT ` then like `-t nat -A PREROUTING -s CLIENT_IP -d 8.8.8.8 -j DNAT --to 8.8.8.8`. I haven't tested any of this so overall it's just going to take experimentation. It sounds like what you want to do is totally doable with iptables.